# discord.js - validate embed?

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

I want to validate a discord embed before sending it.
Which means, I want to know if an embed has nothing wrong with it before actually sending it on a channel.

```
var embed = {
  title: 'some title',
  description: 'some description',
  color: 'foo bar'
}

// embed.color is not a valid color, so it will trigger an error when I send it.
// Here I want some way to know that there's something wrong with the embed object.

message.channel.send({embed});
```

Comment: You could simply use a json validator...a good one is here https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv

Comment: Discord embeds have limits on some individual properties. In combination with ajv and [the limit information here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-limits), that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a function to validate embeds. However, it's incomplete and may have false positives or false negatives, but it should meet your needs.

```js
function validURL(url) {
  try {
    new URL(url);
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function validEmbed(embed) {
  return Object.entries({
    title: (title) => typeof title === 'string',
    description: (description) => typeof description === 'string',
    url: (url) => validURL(url),
    timestamp: (timestamp) => (new Date(timestamp)).getTime() > 0,
    color: (color) => typeof color === 'number',
    fields: (fields) => fields.every(field => typeof field.name === 'string' && typeof field.value === 'string' && typeof field.inline === 'boolean'),
    thumbnail: (thumbnail) => validURL(thumbnail.url),
    image: (image) => validURL(image.url),
    author: (author) => typeof author.name === 'string' && validURL(author.url) && validURL(author.icon_url),
    footer: (footer) => typeof footer.text === 'string' && validURL(footer.icon_url)
  }).every(field => {
    if (!(field[0] in embed)) return true;

    return embed[field[0]] && field[1](embed[field[0]]);
  });
}
```

Here is an exaple snippet:

```js
function validURL(e){try{new URL(e)}catch(e){return!1}return!0}function validEmbed(e){return Object.entries({title:e=>"string"==typeof e,description:e=>"string"==typeof e,url:e=>validURL(e),timestamp:e=>new Date(e).getTime()>0,color:e=>"number"==typeof e,fields:e=>e.every(e=>"string"==typeof e.name&&"string"==typeof e.value&&"boolean"==typeof e.inline),thumbnail:e=>validURL(e.url),image:e=>validURL(e.url),author:e=>"string"==typeof e.name&&validURL(e.url)&&validURL(e.icon_url),footer:e=>"string"==typeof e.text&&validURL(e.icon_url)}).every(t=>!(t[0]in e)||e[t[0]]&&t[1](e[t[0]]))}



/* returns true */
console.log(validEmbed({
  title: 'The title'
}));



/* returns true */
console.log(validEmbed({
  title: 'The title',
  description: 'Sample Description.',
  url: 'https://i.imgur.com/ttHwmCl.jpg',
  timestamp: '2020-07-30T14:44:05.876Z',
  color: 3447003,
  fields: [{
      name: 'name',
      value: 'value',
      inline: false
    },
    {
      name: 'name2',
      value: 'value2',
      inline: true
    }
  ],
  thumbnail: {
    url: 'attachment://stackoverflow2.jpg'
  },
  image: {
    url: 'attachment://stackoverflow.jpg'
  },
  author: {
    name: 'Daemon Beast',
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/P4L260P.jpg',
    icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/P4L260P.jpg'
  },
  footer: {
    text: 'footer text',
    icon_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/ttHwmCl.jpg'
  }
}));



/* returns false */
console.log(validEmbed({
  author: 4567876567
}));
```